# Windows Terminal: 4 split panes each running a different command

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-terminal

Using a batch file on Windows 11, I want four panes in one tab of Windows Terminal, each running a different command.

I have achieved the panes with this command:

```bash
wt split-pane -V ; move-focus left ; split-pane -H ; move-focus right ; split-pane -H
```

So, the only thing I need to do still is executing commands on each of these panes. As I've read online, I managed to change the directory of a pane using `-d <dir>`. So, for example:

```bash
wt -d <dir> ; split-pane -V ; ...
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`split-pane` accepts pretty much all the same arguments as `new-tab` does. So, you can just pass the path to each `split-pane` command directly.

In a legible form:

```
wt split-pane -V -d c:\path\to\pane\one -- command_one and args too ; 
   move-focus left ; 
   split-pane -H -d c:\path\to\pane\two -- command_two and args too ; 
   move-focus right ; 
   split-pane -H -d c:\path\to\pane\three -- command_three and args too
```

less legibly:

```
wt split-pane -V -d c:\path\to\pane\one -- command_one and args too ; move-focus left ; split-pane -H -d c:\path\to\pane\two -- command_two and args too ; move-focus right ; split-pane -H -d c:\path\to\pane\three -- command_three and args too
```

shorter:

```
wt sp -V -d c:\path\to\pane\one -- command_one and args too ; mf left ; sp -H -d c:\path\to\pane\two -- command_two and args too ; mf right ; sp -H -d c:\path\to\pane\three -- command_three and args too
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows